# JQuery overriding the themeroller style

Tags: jquery, accordion, themeroller

In my accordian control I want to override the header style to show a red background instead of the default theme colour if ever the user control (e.g user's name and address input) in that particular pane returns a validation boolean of false.

I'm ok with how to use .Toggle to change the class but can't figure out how to grab the themeroller class in the first place.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are Using the jQuery [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

the class is called: **.ui-accordion-header**

so after the validation return false

set the new background color by adding inline style like this:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header').attr('style','background:red');
```

then for remove it:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header').attr('style','');
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming you have this html struct

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        ... <- if your form is here for es.: 
                   your path escalation to it's own H3 would be:

<!--\ $(this).parent('p').parent('div').prev(h3).attr('style','background:red') \-->

        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
     ...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where $(this) refer to the empty Input in the if statment!

```
if ( $('my_input').val() == '' )
$(this).parent().parent().prev().attr('style','background:red');
```

this should work as expected!

Comment: Hi aSeptik,

Yes that certainly worked, thanks. 

All I need now is to figure out how to make it apply to only the particular panes that fail the validation.

I think I can figure out some kind of additional class like "ui-accordion-header-failedvalidation" and toggle the classes in the html with .Toggle.

So it's off to work we go...

All the best

Paul

Comment: Thanks again aSeptik, I followed your logic and was able to make it work, I tailored it a bit.
I used this:  $("h3:first").attr('style', 'background:red'); and planted it inside the panel, now I can attach it to the validation boolean and the .ToggleClass function to get the end result.
Cheers

Comment: Actually, this is the rudimentary model I have now:
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
   <div>
        <p>     
            <button>Input</button>
            <input type="text" value="good" />  
<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
        if ($("Input").val() == "good") {
            $("h3:first").attr('style', 'background:red');
        }       
    });
</script>
        </p>
    </div>
It's just to demonstrate the trigger

Answer (score 0):

A useful way of reverse-engineering something like this is to go into a browser like Firefox or Chrome (others do this as well, but these are the two I use most), right-click on the element, and select "Inspect Element." This will give you a nicely-formatted (at least Firefox formats it, I think Chrome might not) view of the markup, as well as currently applied styles. In addition, that inspector can help you figure out, for example, why your CSS rules aren't applying. You can also create new rules on the fly, which makes the edit-compile-test loop much faster.

Comment: Hi notJim, thanks for this, I did try but can't seem to find the "Inspect Element" menu item wen I right click over the element. Do I need an addon or smething like that?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned, in Firefox I believe you need the Firebug debugger (which is an amazing piece of software). In Chrome, it's built in.